# Enabling WEBDAV to handle paths with & sign

Tags: 2013

We want to set WebDav to handle paths with special characters. We followed this in the documentation for Tridion 2013:

> If some component in name has some special characters < & > # % * : |
> ~ + webdav need to handle this.  To enable WebDAV to handle paths with
> an & sign in the name, you need to update a registry key. Steps to
> execute:
>
> 1. On the Content Manager server, open the Registry Editor.
> 2. Navigate to the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET
> 3. Add a new key to this key called VerificationCompatibility (a DWORD) and set it to the value 1. To learn more about this issue,
>    refer to Microsoft Knowledge Base Article 826437
>    (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826437)

However, this solution explained above didn’t help in our case and after creating one component with special character & in Tridion, and opening that component with webdav following error appeared.

[image]

Comment: Can you please try to add `<system.web><httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" /></system.web> under <configuration>` section in `%tridion_home%/webdav/web.config`? This solution is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
</system.web>
```

under `<configuration>` section in %tridion_home%/webdav/web.config? This solution is provided here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client